# How to copy data from one worksheet to another (using an indirect reference for the latter worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add some simple VBA functions to excel files at work (i work for a marketing company) and am struggling to code a button that can copy data from one sheet to another (the position it needs to copy to changes daily)

I'm using VBA to try and select the range of values i need copied (and it works) but i'm struggling to paste them in the daily-changing cells required.
I've tried writing a formula that presents a pathway to the correct cells and then introducing an indirect function to the VBA code for pasting but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
Sub Gross_Wrap_Click()

Sheets("AUTOM").Select
Range("C1:C5").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Daily").Select
Range([indirect("'AUTOM!O7'")]).Select
Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

I expect the end product to be the contents of cells C1:C5 in the AUTOM sheet copied and pasted to the required cells in the DAILY sheet (the required cells are derived from a function and included in VBA with an Indirect pathway).

However, i'm just getting a load of different error messages

Comment: Should the cells be pasted next to a certain date (e.g. today or yesterday) on the Daily sheet?

Comment: @BigBen Yes, not in a cell directly next to the date, but in the same column as yesterdays date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't messed it reading your code, this should do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range 'Range object, means a cell or a range of cells
    With ThisWorkbook 'here you reference the workbook, so you don't need to write Thisworkbook everytime, just "."
        Set rng = .Sheets("Daily").Find(.Sheets("AUTOM").Range("O7")) 'we set the object rng to the cell in sheets Daily which has the Cell O7 from AUTOM sheet value.
        .Sheets("AUTOM").Range("C1:C5").Copy 'copy the range from AUTOM
        rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'and paste it's values to the range object we declared and defined above
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! i'll give it a go, I'm pretty new to this stuff, would you mind talking me through what each line does a little bit?

Comment: @Liam there, hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at the moment (Error message: "Object doesn't support this property or method"), is this because the range isn't being referred to properly (the range of cells needed is specified in O7 via a formula i.e. formula produces "Mq7:Mq9" within the cell)

Comment: @Liam try changing `.Find` for `.Range`  and add after `.Range("O7")` this `.Value`

Comment: that works, however, is there a way i can get it to copy the values in the cells only, and not the formulas and the formatting? Thank you!

Comment: @Liam edited my answer, check it out. Consider accepting it now that everything is sorted.